# Android Dependency Error - Can't determine type for tag '<macro name="m3_comp_assist_chip_container_shape">?attr/shapeAppearanceCornerSmall</macro>'

Tags: android, react-native, macros

I'm having a problem with running my android app:

```
Can't determine type for tag '<macro name="m3_comp_assist_chip_container_shape">?attr/shapeAppearanceCornerSmall</macro>'
```

Not able to solve this.

I have tried updating the below libraries based on the answers provided in stackoverflow but it didn't helped.

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Not really a great answer, but what worked for me was finding the package that depended on a newer version of material and downgrading. You can find the transitive package dependencies with `./gradlew app:dependencies`. For me the offending package was `react-native-screens@^3.29.0`

Comment: How did you solve it then? downgrade react-native-screens to a particular version?

Comment: Yes, exactly :(

Comment: i had "react-native-screens": "^3.13.1", it was working before, so now I am using this "3.13.1" I remove ^.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution for the problem.

I changed compileSdkVersion from 31 to 33 and it worked without a gradle upgrade.
My gradle version is 7.1.1

> implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'

> implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'

Make these changes with the above versions and the error would be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue happened for in for android in the react native project.

I am mentioning the steps which solved my issue.

1. Revert all the changes done including the "Package.json", cause you might have changed any version of any libraries in the package.json. Then install node_modules and try running the app.
2. If the above step doesn’t solve your problem, then search for "com.google.android.material:material" in your react native project and change the version for the same if it is more than 1.6.0. Then check running the app.
   for me it was `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'` Then after reverting all the changes, now it is `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'`.
3. If all the above steps don’t work, then you may uninstall and install the android studio, SDK and other Android studio-related dependencies.